# Drag and Drop GridView Rows using TableDnD

Tags: c#, jquery, .net, gridview

I have a GridView with draggable and droppable rows. I'm using tableDnD to accomplish this. The drag and drop part is working fine. The problem i'm facing is when i try to get the data of the reordered grid when i need to save it back to the DB. My code looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var strorder;

    function reorder(table, row) {
        if (!table)
            table = $("#<%= gdvSteps.ClientID %>")[0];

        var rows = table.tBodies[0].rows;
        var step = 1;
        for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
            strorder = strorder + $(".orderbox", rows[i]).html + "|";
            $(".orderbox", rows[i]).html(step++);
            strorder = strorder + $(".orderbox", rows[i]).html + ";";
        }
    }

    $(document).on('click', '#<%=btnSave.ClientID %>', function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Test_Grid.aspx/GridViewReorders",
            data: '{"Reorder":"' + strorder + '"}',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            async: true,
            cache: false,
            success: function (msg) {
                alert("successful!" + msg.d);
            }
        })
        return false;
    });

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#<%= gdvSteps.ClientID %>").tableDnD({
            dragHandle: ".dragHandle",
            onDrop: reorder
        });            

        $("#<%= gdvSteps.ClientID %> tr").hover(function () {
            $(this.cells[0]).addClass('showDragHandle');
        }, function () {
            $(this.cells[0]).removeClass('showDragHandle');
        });
    });

</script>

<div>
<asp:GridView ID="gdvSteps" runat="server" OnRowEditing="gdvSteps_RowEditing"
 OnRowUpdating="gdvSteps_RowUpdating" OnRowCancelingEdit="gdvSteps_RowCancelingEdit"
    AutoGenerateColumns="false">
    <Columns>
        <asp:ImageField ItemStyle-CssClass="dragHandle">
        </asp:ImageField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Step" HeaderText="P" ItemStyle-CssClass="orderbox" ItemStyle-Width="10px" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Sistem">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblSistem" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Sistem") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlSistem" runat="server" DataTextField="SUP_MCH_CODE" DataValueField="SUP_MCH_CODE"
                    OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlSistem_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true">
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemStyle Width="40px" />
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Box">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Box") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlBox" runat="server" DataTextField="MCH_CODE" DataValueField="OBJID">
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemStyle Width="40px" />
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Job">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblJob" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Job") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlJob" runat="server" DataTextField="Job" DataValueField="IDJob">
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemStyle Width="300px" />
            <FooterStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Observations">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblObservations" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Observations") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtObservations" runat="server" DataTextField="Observations" DataValueField="Observations">
                </asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Executant">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblExecutant" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Executant") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlExecutant" runat="server" DataTextField="Executant" DataValueField="IDExecutant">
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemStyle Width="250px" />
            <FooterStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:ImageButton ID="btnEdit" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Edit"
                    ImageUrl="~/Imagenes/Edit.png" Text="Edit" />
            </ItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <asp:ImageButton ID="btnUpdate" runat="server" CausesValidation="True" ImageUrl="~/Imagenes/Ok.png"
                                CommandName="Update" Text="Update"></asp:ImageButton>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:ImageButton ID="btnCancel" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" ImageUrl="~/Imagenes/Cancel.png"
                                CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel"></asp:ImageButton>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </EditItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:ImageButton ID="btnDelete" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Delete"
                    ImageUrl="~/Imagenes/Delete.png" Text="Delete" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
<asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" Text="Save" />
</div>
```

And the codebehind function i'm calling is this:

```
[WebMethod]        
public static string GridViewReorders(string Reorder)
{        
    return Reorder.Split(';')[0];
}
```

For the time being i'm just testing if i can get the data when i hit the Save button.

The thing is that when i hit the button before reordering the rows it works fine. The method is being called and the alert message is being showed. But if i hit the button after reordering the rows, the button, does nothing and the method is not being called.

I don't know if this is the best way to get the data of the reordered rows back. And i don't know why the button, or the method, stops working after the reordering.

Any help will be appreciated!

Here are the links that helped me build this:

http://isocra.com/2008/02/table-drag-and-drop-jquery-plugin/

http://aspdotnet-example.blogspot.com.ar/2011/10/gridview-reorder-row-drag-and-drop.html

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little late to your post. I'm sure by now you've already come up with an alternative solution. But, I thought I'd add that I also had the same problem you did and thought I would contribute with my own battle with this.

Initially, I had my gridview inside of an updatepanel.  When I moved a row using tablednd, the results would come back correctly as far as the reordering.  I'm using Ajax and webmethods similar to what you have.  I would do a split with a webmethod to get the Id and new SortOrder for each row and do a mass update.

The gotcha however was that the grid no longer allowed you to move anything after it rendered the new ordering where I would trigger a click event for a hidden asp button to repopulate the grid.

The hidden button is being used because the Webmethod could only handle the Reordering and the hidden button had to be called to rebind the gridview.  So, I ended up with this below.

```
 $(document).ready(function ()
    {
        $('#gvLocations').tableDnD({
            onDrop: function (table, row)
            {
                var serialize = $.tableDnD.serialize();//$('#gvLocations').tableDnDSerialize();

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "RowsUpDownOrDragging.aspx/RowOrderSerialize",
                    data: "{sortedIDs: '" + serialize + "'}",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: OnSuccess
                });
            }
        });

        function OnSuccess()
        {
            location.reload();
            //$("#ReloadThePanel").trigger("click");  //hidden button
        }
    });
```

When I comment out/remove the UpdatePanel wrapper, I am able to reorder the grid and not lose the tablednd functionality.  So, there appears to be a disconnect with tablednd getting confused for a partial rebinding.

Anyway, if you look closer at the OnSuccess method, I'm now using the location.reload() as the hidden button became overkill.  I'm not happy that I have to do a full page refresh.  But, everything does work correctly with my code this way.

Edit: Sure enough after posting this yesterday, I came across [this website](http://forums.asp.net/t/1684346.aspx?tableDnD%20onDragClass%20not%20working%20on%20asp%20net%20GRIDVIEW) - that addresses the partial postback occurring in the updatepanel affecting the ability to continue dragging rows around.  The key line is this

```
 Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(gvLocations_LazyLoad);
```

Once I started using this, I could do a partial update rather than a full page reload.